# How to - each RadComboBox in column inside RadGridView with unique data?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik, radcombobox, radgridview

Here is what I want to achieve:

I have RadGridView, let's call it gridView, with two columns - first contains ordinary text (GridViewDataColumn), second is a GridViewComboBoxColumn. Each row consist of property (first column) and possible values (displayed in comboBox in second column) which vary for each property. For example:

Property: border
Possible values: solid, dash

Property: font-family
Possible values: arial, times new roman

The problem is that I can set data source for whole column but not for individual ComboBoxes - or at least I don't know these controls good enough.

Data is bound correctly, but the only thing missing is separate data source for each comboBox. How to achieve that?

I'm using Silverlight 4, Telerik controls Q1 2010 SP2

Comment: Are you using Telerik's Silverlight Controls or Silverlight 4 plus some other Telerik controls package? If the former, I probably can't be much help. I'm only familiar with their ASP.NET AJAX controls, but I figured I'd ask to see if I can be of assistance.

Comment: I'm using SL 4 + some Telerik constrols. As for now, I've implemented combobox column for DataGrid which is filled with custom values taken from my class. This solution works very good (just like I wanted to), however I'm still interested in solving stated problem.

Comment: You can use GridViewComboBoxColumn ItemsSourceBinding to achieve this - different source for each combo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlad's comment contained solution to problem:

> You can use GridViewComboBoxColumn ItemsSourceBinding to achieve this - different source for each combo.

Thanks.